# My cat sometimes eats random things at night, and has no appetite the next day

Tags: cats, eating

My wife and I have a 2 year old tuxedo American shorthair cat. Half a year ago had to take her to the vet because she had something stuck in her stomach (might be some carpet). She was refusing to eat and was vomiting.

Today we woke up, and our cat has no appetite, she just sits and doesn't move much, and refuses to eat her favorite treats (even churro!). No vomiting this time. We're taking her to the vet, and we suspect she might have eaten something she shouldn't have overnight.

Wondering if anyone has had a similar situation with their cats.

EDIT:
My questions are: What should be done about this situation? Has anyone successfully tackled it? Or should I just accept having to go to the vet every few months when my cat runs around and eats thing she should not eat!

2nd EDIT:
She had a fever and just needed antibiotics. I had jumped the gun in assuming she eaten something she ought not have eaten! Although at some extent the issue remains at some level - my cats find random small trinkets to paw around at night and sometimes chew at a bit.

Comment: Do you have any specific question?

Comment: Welcome! This is a site for question and answers  So please give a question, or an aim you want to reach. Then the answers will be more focussed and useful for you. Do you want to stop the cat? Do you want to know what is harmful and should be removed? Do you want to know how to bring the cat to the vet? You see... clearification is needed.

Comment: Vet first. As described this could be anything, not even necessarily related to the GI tract or anything she might have eaten

Comment: Modified my post to have questions - sorry about that!

Comment: I'm not sure even with the questions added that this is effectively answerable; you "suspect" the cat ate something overnight that caused her to not eat today, but you have no confirmation at this time (something the vet will have to handle). Two of my cats recently refused to eat. One had a bad tooth, the other just didn't like her food; neither is related to "eating something they shouldn't," and you don't know that your cat's situation right now is, either.

Comment: 1/2  :( A dillemma for sure, I'm so sorry. I would be worried (and asking the same questions of myself) too, if I were in your situation. Though it's unpleasant to contemplate, finances may matter. One of my dogs has eaten everything you can imagine (I'm not exaggerating too much.) I'm on a fixed income, and the vet is very expensive. The first time he ate a large sock, he went to the vet. Another time, he swallowed a large **heavy** plastic bag (I was in a wheelchair and didn't reach him quickly enough to take it away, and seeing my rush towards him, he gobbled it down in its entirety.

Comment: 2/2:  I was heartbroken, waiting for a bowel obstruction. (I did give him an emetic, though. It didn't work.) He passed it *intact*. Unfreakingbelievable! He does this stuff all the time; he's either too smart or too dumb for me (he even managed to get on top of my refrigerator to eat a whole loaf of bread!!!) If and when he gets a hint of a bowel obstruction, I will break down and take him to the vet for surgery, but until then, it's watch, wait, love, enjoy, teach, play, and try to keep *everything* out of reach.

Comment: Maybe it would be useful to ask for signs of obstruction, or for signs to notice that the cat ate something dangerous (in an additional question) so it may be more easy to choose if the cat need to see a vet or not?